# Is there a way to replace the character value of " - " (including the brackets " ") with just the NULL expression in the column of a dataframe?

Tags: r

So far, I have used this:

```
nyc_data$SALE.PRICE <- gsub(" -  ", "" , as.character(nyc_data$SALE.PRICE))
```

However, this only replaces the first argument with the second argument. So the output is "". For instance:

Output before: " -  "
Output after:  ""

Does anyone have any suggestions? Unfortunately, I am not permitted to share any of the data.

Comment: You can surely post some sample data...

Comment: @cmvrdr_1 Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69886605) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend the intuitive [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package for transformations.

**NOTE:** In R one can't indicate a "blank cell" with [`NULL`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/NULL.html): that indicates a missing *object* (like a column), rather than a missing value (like a "cell"). For "cells" you should use [`NA`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/NA.html), coerced to the appropriate datatype for the column: [`as.character`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/character.html)`(NA)`.

```
library(dplyr)

nyc_data %>%
  mutate(
    # Transform the 'SALE.PRICE' column...
    SALE.PRICE = if_else(
      # ...by checking which values are the entire string " - "...
      grepl("^ - $", SALE.PRICE),
      # ...and replacing them with "blanks" ('NA's)...
      as.character(NA),
      # ...while leaving the others unchanged.
      SALE.PRICE
    )
  )
```